# MongoError: connection timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**I am facing mongoDB time out connection error**.

Here I have modified in a code by

```
MongoClient.connect(uristring, {
            server: {
                socketOptions: {
                    keepAlive: 300000,
                    connectTimeoutMS: 30000
                },
                auto_reconnect: true
            }
        }, function(error, db) {
  if (!error) {
     callback(null, db);
  } else {
     callback(error);
  }
});
```

but no solution comes.Please help me I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb default Time out is 30 seconds, you got the timeout error means your query takes more than 30 seconds to get data.

You can either

- increase timeout time from 30 seconds to a larger value.
- optimize your query makes it faster.

Comment: I have increased time period by 60 second that time working fine but now same `mongoconnection` error are showing.

1.How much we increased timeout connection..Beacuse we have 10 milions records in DB.
2. I have optimized a query as much as possible.